# How to get store app version from C# using PowerShell?

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core

I don't know why the results Collection is empty?
How to get the exact output of a PowerShell command?

```cs
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace MyApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
            var results = ps.AddScript("(Get-AppxPackage \"Adobe.CC.XD\" | Select Version).Version").Invoke();

            Console.WriteLine("Press a key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have that package installed, but `(Get-AppxPackage "Microsoft.AccountsControl" | Select Version).Version` returns "10.0.17763.1"

Comment: Yes, the command works perfectly in PowerShell, but I can’t make it working from C# with the PowerShell object.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround without using the PowerShell object.

```cs
static string GetStoreAppVersion(string appName)
{
    var process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo =
        {
            FileName = "powershell.exe",
            Arguments = $"-Command (Get-AppxPackage \"{appName}\" | Select Version).Version",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        }
    };

    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();

    var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    var version = output.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(version))
    {
        return null;
    }

    return version;
}
```